# phantomJS javascript

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm trying to lean PhantomJS. I need to log into a website, and perform some basic crawling.
The following code is breaking with this error:

```
undefined:12 SyntaxError: Parse error
```

My code:

```
var loginKronos = function (url, username, password) {

var page = new WebPage();

page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('FAIL to load the address');
    }; 
    else {
        //t = Date.now() - t;
        //console.log('Loading time ' + t + ' msec');
        console.log('Loading time ' + t + ' msec');
    };

};

var username = 'me';
var password = 'passwd';
var baseurl = 'http://golfing.com/';

loginKronos ( baseurl, username, password );

phantom.exit();
```

Comment: There are a lot of syntax errors in your code. There are too many semi colons all over the place and you haven't closed your anonymous function, which makes me think this syntax error could be outside the snippet you posted as it's pretty obscure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You (at the very least) forgot a parenthesis.

Also, you don't put semicolons after closing braces on if / else statements

```
page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('FAIL to load the address');
    } // <---------- removed semicolon
    else {
        //t = Date.now() - t;
        //console.log('Loading time ' + t + ' msec');
        console.log('Loading time ' + t + ' msec');
    }  // <----------- removed semicolon

});   // <------------- added a paren
```